# System.Drawing.Image.FromStream not found WP8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

i tried to use the `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream` in my code but visual studio didn't know
i've added as reference  `Microsof.Expression.Drawing`

```
>            var contactImg = e.Results.Select(x =>>x.GetPicture()).FirstOrDefault();
>                 if (contactImg != null)
>                 {
>                     imagelable = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(contactImg);
>                 }
```

any thing is missing ? thanks

Comment: XAML-based technologies don't support dinosaur `System.Drawing` stuff. There must be a `System.Windows` or `Windows.UI` equivalent of what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as XAML don't support dinosaur **System.Drawing**
i have made same changes an it works, the code become like this

```
var contactImg = e.Results.Select(x => x.GetPicture()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (contactImg != null)
            {
                BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage();
                bm.SetSource(contactImg);
                imagelable.Source = bm;
                MessageBox.Show(c.DisplayName);
            }
```